# alternative to JSONObject in java

Tags: java, android, json

I've been using JSONObject as return types on most of my classes and methods for android to aid in debugging and informing the user of the problems. But I've been trying to build an AsyncTask JSONObject has been getting quirky. Is there any multi-type array that can be used to transport primitive data-types in one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using a

```
 Bundle
```

would be helpful?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Answer (score 0):

If the type doesnt need to be preserved, you could always convert your data to Strings and transport that instead.  Then you could use whatever you want; an array, an ArrayList, etc.

If you need to preserve the type, you can use a second value to denote the type.  Oryou could still use whatever data structure fits your needs performance-wise and store Object instances; Character for chars, Integer for ints, etc. and then on retrieval, use reflection to get their type info.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a little more info, I'd possibly look into using Gson since you say that JSONObject has been quirky for you.  I've been using it and haven't had any problems so far:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/